# How to get the value from a tag in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can we get the value inside the value section in selenium

I need to retrieve Mr in a string present under value using selenium.

Since its not a free text so getText() is not working.

Comment: Please share the URL and HTML

Comment: <input class=“title” value=“Mr”

Comment: You want to return Mr

Comment: Yes i need that in a string

Comment: Okay i will give u code

Comment: Can u paste complete HTML of that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement you can try this

it is your HTML code:

```
 <input class="title" type="text" value="Mr">
```

Selenium code:

```
 String textvalue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Mr']")).getAttribute("value");

 System.out.println(textvalue);
```

Comment: @dheeraj try this

Answer (score 1):

for python:

```
value=driver.find_element_by_id('tag ID')
print(value.text)
```

java:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id('tag ID')).getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the get attribute method

```
value = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'title')
output = value.get_attribute("value")
```